# searching for strings containing special characters in vim

Tags: vim

How can I search for the following string in vim:

```
\$5 * \$5 * \$6 * 10000
```

Just typing

```
/\$5 * \$5 * \$6 * 10000
```

in command mode doesn't do the job.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `\` before `\` (double `\\`), `$`, and `*`.

```
/\\\$5 \* \\\$5 \* \\\$6 \* 1000\\\$5 \* \\\$5 \* \\\$6 \* 10000
```

Comment: I think the triple \ is not necessary -- my copy of Vim is finding the text with just a double \ (in other words, "/\\$5 \* \\$5 \* \\$6 \* 10000" also is working for me).  I think the $ character doesn't need the \ in this context, since it can't mean "end of line" here?

Comment: I believe Vim's escaping behavior depends on the config, that could be why it's different.